# I can't figure out what to put in place of the integer amount in the try block in actionPerformed?

Tags: java, jframe

It's a course project and I'm trying to set up an EF Scale Reporter with a GUI and it keeps erroring out telling me that I have a NumberFormatException for a string input.

don't mind the calculator names... it was just used as a template from something else

Also, It's the try block in the submitButtonClicker class, which is where I need assistance and I can't seem to figure out what I need to do in replace of the integer amount

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
        import java.util.InputMismatchException;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JLabel;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        import javax.swing.JTextField;

        public class CalcButtonFrame extends JFrame{

            private JLabel instructions = new JLabel("Please enter windspeed: ");
            private JTextField firstNumber = new JTextField(5);
            private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
            private JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
            private JLabel lowSpeed = new JLabel("65");
            private JLabel highSpeed = new JLabel("200");

            CalcDrawing drawing = new CalcDrawing();

            public CalcButtonFrame() {

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(instructions);
                panel.add(firstNumber);
                panel.add(submit);
                panel.add(clear);
                panel.add(drawing);

                drawing.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 60));

                ClearButtonListener cbl = new ClearButtonListener();
                clear.addActionListener(cbl);

                SubmitButtonListener sbl = new SubmitButtonListener();
                submit.addActionListener(sbl);
                add(panel);

            }


        class ClearButtonListener implements ActionListener{

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                firstNumber.setText("");

                Calculator empty = new Calculator();
                drawing.adjustFill(empty.determinePercentage());

            }

        }

        class SubmitButtonListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText());
                    firstNumber.setText(String.valueOf(amount));        


                    Integer high = Integer.parseInt(highSpeed.getText());
                    highSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(high));        

                    Calculator user = new Calculator(amount, high);

                    //after creating the percentage method
                    drawing.adjustFill(user.determinePercentage());

                }
                catch(NumberFormatException Exception) {
                    String a = firstNumber.getText();
                    int amount = Integer.parseInt(a);

                    String l = lowSpeed.getText();
                    double low = Double.parseDouble(l);

                    if(amount < low){

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be greater than 65");
                    }

                }

                try {       
                    Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText());
                    firstNumber.setText(String.valueOf(amount));        

                    Integer high = Integer.parseInt(highSpeed.getText());
                    highSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(high));

                    Calculator user = new Calculator(amount, high);

                    //after creating the percentage method
                    drawing.adjustFill(user.determinePercentage());

                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e1) {
                        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                        JLabel enter = new JLabel("Please enter a number");
                        panel.add(enter);
                        System.out.println("not working");
                }



                }
        }
        }

    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class CalcDrawing extends JComponent{

    private int x= 10;
    private int y = 10;
    private int totalLength = 170;
    private int height = 30;
    //create another variable after adjustFill
    private int fillForFirstSection = 170;

    //rectangle 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x, y, totalLength, height);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x, y, fillForFirstSection, height);

    }

    public void adjustFill(double fillAmount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double fill = totalLength * fillAmount;
        fillForFirstSection = (int)fill;
        repaint();

    }
}

    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class StartCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JFrame frame = new CalcButtonFrame();
            frame.setSize(400, 200);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}




public class Calculator {
    private double amount;
    private int maxMPH = 200;

    public Calculator() {
        //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public Calculator(double amount, int maxMPH) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.maxMPH = maxMPH;
    }

    //getters and setters

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    //new method
    public double determinePercentage() {
        return (int)this.amount/(int)this.maxMPH;
    }


}
```

Comment: `int amount = Integer.parseInt(a);` inside the `catch` block could trigger another `NumberFormatException`

Comment: If you want our help debuting your code, you'll need to provide a [mcve] first

Comment: Ok! Is that better? Or do I still need to do something else? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Can it be compiled? Can it be run? Does it only include what is required to replicate the issue?

Comment: Yes, I think so! I don't know what else I would use besides stating that I used eclipse for this project?

Comment: But there's no `main` method, so it can't be run.  Remember, people will copy and paste this code into their IDEs, if it takes more than a second to get it running, most people will delete it, close the tab and move. It's in your best interests to make people's life as easy as possible ;)

Comment: Yes, there is... it's in the zip that I included. Is that not the way I'm supposed to do it lol.

Comment: You're on the internet, some stranger asks you to download a zip file, what would you do?

Comment: lol, that's true... ya got me there... I'll update it

Comment: All good to go! @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at...

```
try {
    Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText());
    //...
} catch (NumberFormatException Exception) {
    String a = firstNumber.getText();
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(a);
    //...
}
```

If `Integer amount = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText());` fails, then there is no point in trying `int amount = Integer.parseInt(a);` in the `catch` block, as it's already failed.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense! Thanks! I really appreciate your help and as you can obviously tell that I'm new around here. So thanks for showing me how things work!